# "With Automatic Weights" not showing under "Set Parent To" tab

Tags: armature

I was following a tutorial by Grant Abbitt here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAiTYaiZmY0&t=36s and at time stamp 5:50 "With Automatic Weights" under the Set Parent To" tab isn't showing up for me. The only thing I did different was I extruded all the bones instead of using the copy paste method as I wanted the head (last bone) to be a bit longer. Also i'm not sure if the bones are parenting to the mesh because the yellow outline disappears on my mesh when I click on the bones to parent the two as seen at time stamp 5:38. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I'm a noob but excited to learn all I can and this problem has brought m to a stand still.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). As Grant Abbitt said: "you may have selected in the wrong order".

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ So I would select the mesh first by left clicking, then the bones by left clicking? Thanks for responding so quick. I wasn't expecting a response so quick lol.